# What instrument(s) lend themselves to playing different dynamics rapidly?

Tags: rhythm, dynamics, orchestration

I'm a composer. What instrument(s) would it be easiest to play parts like this on? Thinking along the lines of unpitched percussion, but I'm open to anything.  For example: [image]

Comment: Easier question to answer is which instruments *can't* do that.

Comment: @tim With more than 13 notes/attacks per second I assume you are joking.

Comment: @guidot - now, you'll never know!

Answer (score 3):

probably guitar, with the versatility of the picking techniques on hand, a wide range of dynamics come up

Answer (score 3):

I would say many woodwinds, brass, and strings (violin etc).  This is a matter of body control more so than a limitation of the instrument.  One example of an instrument that might not be able to play it is a harpsichord.  I don't think a guitar would provide that much versatility that you could accent, hold for full count at different subdivisions at that speed.  You are not looking at dynamics only but also sustain and at that speed most guitarists would get the accent okay but everything would be staccato.  My bet would be with a clarinet.

Comment: Quadruple tonguing, anyone?

Comment: Practice makes perfect.

Comment: I'd love to find out who coined that phrase - 'cos strictly speaking it's not true! If you practise something badly, though, I suppose it would turn out perfectly bad..?

Comment: How about, perfect practice improves technique and dexterity.

Comment: Getting there!!

Answer (score 1):

You know how fast 16th notes are at 200 bpm, right? They’re pretty much a blur. I would say medium to high pitched stick percussion like a snare drum is your best bet. Forget the tenuto markings, they have no effect on most percussion instruments.

Comment: "The tenuto articulation is often used to indicate a slight raise in dynamic, less than a normal accent." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percussion_notation

Comment: I stand corrected, in that case leave them in. But at that velocity how much articulation can you expect to  get out of a musician?

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy - Likely a substantial amount, given that I've seen drum cadence scores with similar attention to accent detail and *really* fast notes (e.g. 16th-note sextuplets).

Comment: @Dekkadeci At 200bpm? I tip my hat to them, and I’m not being facetious!

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy - The few performances of drum cadences I've viewed on YouTube look *spectacular*.